# How to design Login Page for android app using kivy

Tags: android, kivy

I am trying to build a simple Android app with sign - up and login features using Kivy. For now just to test I have made desktop application in Ubuntu, below is the screenshot.

[image]

After deploying the image to phone I get this result:

[image]

How can I set the size and position of TextInput, Labels and Button so that it gives the right results according to a android application. Below is my .kv code

```
<LoginPage>
Widget:
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            source: 'data/reso.png'
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Label:
        center_x: (root.width/2)
        top: (root.top/2) + 250
        text: "TESTING"
        color: [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.4]
        font_size: 34

    TextInput:
        id: username
        center_x: (root.width/2) 
        top: (root.top/2)+ 100
        size_hint: None,None
        hint_text: "username"
        background_color: [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.4]
        size: 250, 35
        max_lines: 1
        valign: 'middle'
        halign: 'center'
        font_size: 15
        multiline: False
        on_text_validate: root.validate();

    TextInput:
        id: password
        center_x: (root.width/2)
        top: (root.top/2) + 50
        size_hint: None, None
        hint_text: "password"
        background_color: [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.4]
        size: 250, 35
        max_lines: 1
        valign: 'middle'
        halign: 'center'
        font_size: 15
        multiline: False
        password: True

    Button:
        size: 90,35
        pos: 350, 200
        font_size: 18
        background_color: (1,1,1,0.1)
        text: "Login"
```

Please guide. Thank you.

Comment: sir but  even after giving the layouts, how can I determine the correct size and pos according to the window size in Kivy

Comment: @shruti: What result do you actually want? You already positioned things according to the position and size of your root widget, which is the same as doing so with respect to the window. That said, I recommend using Kivy's [layout classes](http://kivy.org/docs/gettingstarted/layouts.html) instead of reinventing them this way. You can use pos and size hints to achieve the sizes and shapes you want.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation gives all the information required.

http://kivy.org/docs/pdf/Kivy-latest.pdf